# Rufus::Scheduler join can not exit at last in ruby

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks, rufus-scheduler

i use Rufus::Scheduler to schedule a task, the code is listed below:

```
class Scheduler
  def self.run
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
    job = scheduler.in '5s', A.new
    scheduler.join
  end
  class A
    def call(job)
      puts "xxxxxx"
    end
  end
end
Scheduler.run
```

after running the code, it has print 'xxxx', but after running the call method, the join can not exit by itself and always hang-up.

is there some way to exit the join after waiting to finish the job? thank u.

Comment: Is there somebody who knows how to stop a scheduled job elegantly?

Comment: Can someone answer my question? thank you in advance.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use plain Thread can reach the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler is meant to run "forever". Calling "join" joins the scheduler thread and only exits when the thread dies.

You should reconsider your code, you're trying to use a hammer like a screwdriver.

Comment: for Thread, when the joined thread finished all the things, the main thread will exit, the way is more reasonable. for scheduler i think it should be, but it's not. now what i want is it has the function of schedule, join and can exit by itself instead of forever.

Comment: No.

If you need to exit after a job, simply sleep, do the job and exit.

Comment: not reasonable, different job needs different time to finish, it's not predictable, how to set the time for sleep, not practical

Comment: you should not use rufus-scheduler.

Comment: @jmettraux if not rufus-scheduler, then what should i use?

Comment: use something you understand.